# Kerberos Delegation (Double-Hop) with pymssql

Tags: python, kerberos, freetds, pymssql, kerberos-delegation

The [`pymssql`](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/index.html) module claims to support Kerberos Authentication (and delegation) and yet I can't seem to enable it.

The client I am running is on Windows. I need to connect with a double-hop through a reverse database proxy. The client, the proxy, and the database are all part of the domain. And when I try to connect with SQL Server Manager I am successful. But when I try to connect with the [`pymssql`](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/index.html) module in Python it doesn't work. If I connect directly from the client to the database I am able to get the Kerberos Authentication to work. But again, when I try to go through the proxy it fails.

This leads me to believe that the Kerberos Authentication works, but that the Delegation (double-hop) does not.

According to the [section on FreeTDS](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/freetds.html) I should be able to create a file at `C:/freetds.conf` and it should read connection information from there. I don't seem to be able to verify this in any meaningful way. Additionally, according to [the freetds schema](http://freetds.schemamania.org/userguide/freetdsconf.htm) I should be able add a parameter `enable gssapi delegation` which when enabled (off by default) allows Kerberos Delegation.

**Bottom Line:**
I am looking to enable Kerberos Delegation (so that the double-hop will work) for pymssql on windows.

---

At the moment I have created a file at `C:/freetds.conf` and have tried a few ways to configure it.

```
[global]
enable gssapi delegation = on
```

and

```
[global]
enable gssapi delegation = true
```

Comment: Did you have a change to evaluate my answer?

Comment: A chance, yes. I have been looking for alternative solutions. I have found some, and it is unfortunate I can't use Pymssql. I will accept your answer, and award the bounty. Because you saved me one hell of a long headache if I would try to make it work anyway, in futility. Thanks for your effort, I wish there was a better answer.

Comment: (by better I mean that would let me work with pymssql)

Comment: Are you able to compile that software under Windows? The patch for that is very easy.

Comment: Custom compilation is beyond the scope of what I am looking for. I need this solution to be easily portable.

Comment: this is not my proposal. You make a patch, pull request and FreeTDS gets updated with the next version. That is it. There is portabilitiy issue here in case of the former.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to answer and is rooted in a shortcoming in FreeTDS. You did nothing wrong.

If we take a look at the GSS-API C code of FreeTDS, we see in [lines 307 to 308](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/blob/master/src/tds/gssapi.c#L307-L308)

```
if (tds->login->gssapi_use_delegation)
  gssapi_flags |= GSS_C_DELEG_FLAG;
```

that your config parameter is read in the delegation flag is set.

Since you are on Windows and Windows uses its own flavor of GSS-API, namely SSPI, we have a look at that C code: [lines 273 to 278](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/blob/master/src/tds/sspi.c#L273-L278) do

```
status = sec_fn->InitializeSecurityContext(&auth->cred, NULL, auth->sname,
  ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT 
    | ISC_REQ_CONNECTION | ISC_REQ_ALLOCATE_MEMORY,
  0, SECURITY_NETWORK_DREP,NULL, 0, &auth->cred_ctx, &desc, &attrs, &ts);
```

as you can see, the context flags are not in a variable but passed directly. Neither the config param is evaluated nor `ISC_REQ_DELEGATE` is passed.

**This** is the problem you are seeing. You have two options now:

1. Raise a bug and wait for a fix.
2. Clone from GitHub, fix yourself and issue a pull request.

Side note: there is several stuff I do not like about both code parts at all:

1. SSPI does not perform mutual auth as GSS-API does but should.
2. Context flags are passed pointlessly but features are never used in that C file, e.g., `ISC_REQ_CONFIDENTIALITY | ISC_REQ_REPLAY_DETECT` and `GSS_C_REPLAY_FLAG | GSS_C_INTEG_FLAG`. There are only necessary if you require further transport security which is not employed here.
3. There are probably more stuff to fix but I did not code review it.

I highly recommend to raise some issues here too.